# Can I develop an App that all elements of it are developed with WebKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have to develop an Application.There is just a `UITabBarController`, others are all developed with `WebKit`.I am going to rebuild the APP,but I have to make it in AppStore first.I guess that it will be refused by Apple.Hope some advice.thx

Comment: I do not entirely understand your question, but are you trying to create an app that will solely contain a `UITabBarController`, whereas each tab contains a `UIWebView`?

Comment: That's right.Each tab contains just a `UIWebView`.our project is completed by HTML5

Comment: I think it would be accepted, although I do recommend building a native experience

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be accepted. If you look at the official drudge report app it is just a ui webview with similar tabbar controls.

I don't know the nature of your project so the drudge app might not be close to what you are thinking.

Comment: my project is completed by HTML5.It is a project about travel.